# UseLATEX in custom target

Tags: cmake, latex, target

I've a `CMakeLists.txt` file that I use for building a set of LaTeX files by using `UseLATEX`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)

project (technical_guide NONE)

include (UseLATEX.cmake)

file (INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tikz DESTINATION ./)
file (INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/code DESTINATION ./)

message (STATUS "TIKZ folder is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_latex_document (
  main.tex
  INPUTS introduction.tex tikzstyle.tex commands.tex codestyle.tex documentstyle.tex
  IMAGE_DIRS tikz
  TARGET_NAME technical_guide
)
```

It works, but I recreate the document every time that I run `cmake --build .`. I want to create a `doc` target and I want to compile documentation only if I select the specific target with the command `cmake --build . --target doc`. How can I modify this file in order to set the custom target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude the target from the `all` using `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` and you have to add your target as a dependency of `doc`. Maybe `EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULTS` is handy, too.

This should do the trick:

```
# create target doc
add_custom_target(doc)
# create target for main.tex, but exclude from all
add_latex_document(
  main.tex
  INPUTS introduction.tex tikzstyle.tex commands.tex codestyle.tex 
  documentstyle.tex
  IMAGE_DIRS tikz
  TARGET_NAME technical_guide
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
# explicitly add dependency to doc
add_dependencies(doc technical_guide)
```

You can also write a function or a macro which does the steps for you and passes all other arguments to `add_latex_document`.